# My page won't load (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm connected to my server via `npm install -g http-server` on `Terminal`, that's working fine. I just want to see if my `h1` tag works so I can proceed to making a practice website. I feel like my `mainPage.html` may be a little off.

Here's my `mainPage.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>

<div id="website"></div>
<script type="text/babel" src="mainPage.js"></script>

</script>
</html>
```

Here's my `mainPage.js` file:

```
var Website = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
        return(
            <h1>Why won't my h1 tag appear!</h1>
        ); 
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Website/>, document.getElementById('website'));
```

Comment: u r using jsx transformer?

Comment: @Nitesh I feel like my code is somewhat close.  I'm just missing a piece or two.

Comment: Actually, I am not able to see any react require/include and babel require in your js. So just asking.

Comment: @Nitesh babel is supposed to be in html file as the script type.

Comment: OK, may be this is also how it works. I am not very sure.And react files, where are you including?

Comment: you use `text/babel`, but there is no babel.js

Comment: Open your console to see if there is any error message

Comment: @CodinCat There are no errors in my console.  I know there's a way to connect my `mainPage.js` to babel so that my code can work properly.  I've done this before a long time ago but I forgot how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import babel.js, react and reactDOM

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.23.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, sir.  Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Include the reference of `react, react-dom and babel`, Check this working code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.23.1/babel.min.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body>

</body>

<div id="website"></div>
<script type="text/babel" >
    var Website = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
        return(
            <h1>Why won't my h1 tag appear!</h1>
        ); 
    }
});
ReactDOM.render(<Website/>, document.getElementById('website'));
</script>

</html>
```